# React - A popup location on top of other popup

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to open a confirmation popup on top of other popup (using carbon modal), but it's located relatively and part o fit is hidden:

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-gould-orhrm?file=/src/App.js)

I tried solving it by css:

```
.container {
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    position: relative !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.on-top {
    /*z-index: 10000;*/
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    /*top: 50%;*/
    /*left: 50%;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't render them as parent-child but as siblings.
The one at the most bottom in the dom will be the top one by default.
You can alter this by giving both modals a different z-index if you want.

Comment: I tried it in my sandbox if you can re-take a look. But in the real scenario, I'm loading a component inside the first modal, and inside that component I have the other modal. So you are suggesting to have both Modals in same component and control it by communication between them...

Comment: Link above still shows the old code.
But yes, I think you get the idea.
I always make modals "dumb" components (not holding their own state or functions).
So you can make a parent component that wraps these 2 modals to share state between them. (Then you don't have to worry about trying to fix this problem with css)